# Access WPF (XAML) Element from F#?

Tags: .net, xaml, f#

Let's say I have this xaml code :

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Name="papan" Fill="Red" Height="20" Width="20" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

And I have a file named Program.fs (F# code), 
how can I access "papan", for example, from my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Markup
open System.Windows.Shapes

let xaml = @"<Window xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
    xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Name='papan' Fill='Red' Height='20' Width='20' />
    </Canvas>
</Window>"

let wnd = XamlReader.Parse(xaml) :?> Window
let rect = wnd.FindName("papan") :?> Rectangle
```

If the XAML is in a separate file, you can use `XamlReader.Load` instead of `XamlReader.Parse`.

Comment: thank you. your answer is very helpful since I am new with WPF.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer posted by kvb, you can use F# dynamic invoke operator (which is similar to `dynamic` in C# 4.0) to get a nicer syntax. The operator allows you to define the meaning of expressions such as `wnd?papan`. You can for example specify that this should perform the lookup using `FindName` method. The operator definition looks like this:

```
let (?) (this : Control) (prop : string) : 'T = // '
  this.FindName(prop) :?> 'T
```

Then you can just write:

```
let rect : Rectangle = wnd?papan
```

You still need to write the type (`Rectangle`) explicitly, so that F# type inference can use it, but the syntax is a bit more comfortable.